# How to apply a function to the field containing selected text, having a form with multiple fields? (Vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

In a form with multiple fields (`<input>` and `<textarea>`), I need to wrap selected text with html tag (namely `<b>`). So I wrote the following code:

```js
const form = document.forms[0];
const fields = form.querySelectorAll("input, textarea");

form.onsubmit = () => {
  formatText("b");
  return false;
}

const formatText = (key) => {
  fields.forEach(el => {
    var start = el.selectionStart;
    var end = el.selectionEnd;
    var len = el.value.length;
    var sel_txt = el.value.substring(start, end);
    if (sel_txt !== "") {
      el.value = el.value.substring(0, start) + `<${key}>${sel_txt}</${key}>` + el.value.substring(end, len);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
input,
textarea {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="a[]" type="text" value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">
  <textarea name="a[]">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</textarea>
  <textarea name="a[]">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</textarea>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It works. But I don't think it's a good solution, because *formatText* function iterates through all form fields, while I would like to apply that function only to the field containing selected text.

How can I do it in Vanilla JavaScript, without any id/class selector?

In other words: **is there a way to know what's the field containing selected text?**

Comment: You could put a class name on all your text fields and then use getelementsbyclassname: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the loop that runs on `submit`, I'd be inclined to use a variable to track which element most recently had focus.

I've suggested using `addEventListener` on all the form elements in scope, and changing the variable to reference the most recently focussed element on each `focus` event.

Upon submitting the form, you can then reference the `selectedField` variable to determine which element to process.

```
<script>
    const form = document.forms[0];
    const fields = form.querySelectorAll("input, textarea");
    
    var selectedField = null;

    fields.forEach(field => {
        field.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
            selectedField = event.target;
        });
    });

    form.onsubmit = () => {
        formatText("b", selectedField);
        return false;
    }

    const formatText = (key, el) => { 
        if(!el) return;
           
        var start = el.selectionStart;
        var end = el.selectionEnd;
        var len = el.value.length;
        var sel_txt = el.value.substring(start, end);
        if (sel_txt !== "") {
            el.value = el.value.substring(0, start) + `<${key}>${sel_txt}</${key}>` + el.value.substring(end, len);
        }
    }
</script>
```

In practice, you would probably want to keep the variable out of the global scope.

I'm not sure how much better this solution is than yours. Perhaps if you have many form fields, it results in less processing work - but you still have to loop through all the elements to add the event listener.